# Javascript: how to get values from all selected checkboxes from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched in many threads but i don't see any checkboxes that involves tables, i just wanted to make deleting easy for users, Say, i have a table with fifty entries and i wanted to delete 10 all in one go, so i select the check box beside each record so when i want to delete it it will just get the values of the checkbox pass it on to a php script..

My question is how do i im[plement this on Javascript or jQuery?. getting the values from n numbers of checkboxes? since tables have a dynamic value depending on how many it has on the database.

Here is an image to be clear:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you an array containing the `value` attribute of each checked box:

```
var values = $('input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/p58Hw/1/

Comment: by the way man, how do you check all checkbox using only one checkbox? its like a select all functionality on checkbox

Comment: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true)`

Answer (score 2):

Select your table, [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) all rows with a [checked checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/), store their values, and remove them:

```
var $chkboxes = $(yourTable).find("tr input[type='checkbox']:checked");
var checkBoxVals = $chkboxes.map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).toArray();

$chkboxes.closest('tr').remove();

// serialize array checkBoxVals and pass it to your php script
```

Comment: nor does he want to simply remove the rows - he needs the values first.

Comment: yep just need the values only of those checked rowws but yeah tnx will try these answers and i'll see which is best

Answer (score 1):

You would post your code. But try something like this:

```
$('.YourCheckboxClass:checked').each(function() {
    // your code here
});
```